# Differentiate between production, staging and test environments in Websphere Commerce

Tags: websphere-commerce, server-configuration

I am new to a WebSphere Commerce Enterprise v6.0 environment that has already been set up. I was wondering what would be the most definitive way for me to determine which servers are used as Production, which are used as Staging and which are used for Testing?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, WCS has so far not included a DB entry or a script that can return the nature of a WCS server. If there is IBM will need to clearly document it.

The best way to find out in [out-of-the-box] WCS installations what is the nature of a WCS server is probably a query like this:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN count(1)>0 THEN 'STAGING'
    WHEN count(1)=0 THEN 'PRODUCTION'
   END AS WCS_TYPE
FROM STAGLOG WHERE STGPROCESSED = 1;
```

(Note: A simpler check could just rely on the existence of the STAGLOG table, but I've seen many WCS servers that have this table without being a Staging server.)

The other option is to add a proprietary/custom system property or WCS server.

Comment: Was this answer applicable/useful?

Answer (score 0):

Non-staging will never have staging triggers.

```
select * from syscat.triggers where trigschema = CURRENT_SCHEMA and trigname like 'STAG%';
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you set it up [http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/tsscreatestagingserver.htm]

To find from DB if the environment is LIVE or STAGING is to query the STAGLOG table.

If we find entries in STAGLOG table, then that is a STAGING environment. This entries are created by TRIGGERS for Staging Database tables.

In LIVE we will not be having entries in STAGLOG table.